# Display in CSS a single icon from image of ten icons where they must be scaled as well?

Tags: html, css, image, scale

In CSS if I have a single file of ten icons 100x100 pixels each. It is `icons.png`.

I want an image in my html

```
<img alt="The third image in the file, but scaled to 30x30"> &nbsp; Menu
```

However, I want the third image in the file (position [200,0] and width 100x100) **BUT** the full 100x100 icon scaled to 30x30 pixels.

Can this be done in CSS/HTML without any javascript?

Comment: your are describing CSS sprites https://www.google.com/search?q=css+sprites&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOiaO3s__dAhUEfFAKHYnpBYAQ7xYIJSgA&biw=1600&bih=789

Comment: check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50301190/css-sprites-will-not-scale/50301296#50301296 .. it's probably all what you need

Answer (score -1):

You could use the :nth-child() selector to select to 3rd child of the parent div.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"> &nbsp; Menu
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"> &nbsp; Menu 
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"> &nbsp; Menu 
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"> &nbsp; Menu 
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"> &nbsp; Menu
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"> &nbsp; Menu
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"> &nbsp; Menu
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"> &nbsp; Menu
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"> &nbsp; Menu
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"> &nbsp; Menu
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
div img:nth-child(3) {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

[Working demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zqyjjg).