# How to properly scale sprites in CSS

Tags: html, css, scale, css-transforms, css-sprites

I'm trying to **automatically scale a text with letters represented by sprites** to make it fit into a div:

[image: Example]

Each letter has specific coordinates in the CSS alphabet sprite image.

**If the text is too long, I dynamically apply a `transform: scale(0.x);` to make it fit properly.**

Everything is working great, but when the scale() is applied, there's a space between each letter that should not be here. It looks like CSS is scaling the sprite properly but does not fix the positioning afterwards.

**Here is a basic reproducible example of 0.5 scale that does not work as expected:**

[image: Basic example]

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width: 114px; height: 63px;"><div class="letter letter-a"></div><div class="letter letter-d"></div></div>
    <div style="width: 114px; height: 63px;"><div class="letter letter-a larger"></div><div class="letter letter-d larger"></div></div>
    <style type="text/css">
        .letter { border: 1px solid red; height: 100%; margin: auto 0; background-image: url(https://ibb.co/gJpYXkW); background-size: auto 153%; }
        .letter-a { width: 59px; display: inline-block; background-position: left -12px top -18px; }
        .letter-d { width: 51px; display: inline-block; background-position: left -187px top -18px; }
        .larger { clear: both; margin-top: 30px; transform: scale(0.5); }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
.letter { border: 1px solid red; height: 100%; margin: auto 0; background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/6FxQpjt/sprite.png'); background-size: auto 153%; }
.letter-a { width: 59px; display: inline-block; background-position: left -12px top -18px; }
.letter-d { width: 51px; display: inline-block; background-position: left -187px top -18px; }
.larger { clear: both; margin-top: 30px; transform: scale(0.5); }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width: 114px; height: 63px;"><div class="letter letter-a"></div><div class="letter letter-d"></div></div>
    <div style="width: 114px; height: 63px;"><div class="letter letter-a larger"></div><div class="letter letter-d larger"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: scale is only a visual transformation so what you have is logical, decrease the width/height instead

Comment: related to get a generic formula of scaling by width/height: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301296/8620333