# CSS background image sprite resizing

Tags: css, image

I have the following CSS code for displaying control buttons on an audio element:

```
background: url("../img/controlSprite.svg") 0 0;
    height: 53px;
    width: 53px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10%;
```

Since the buttons are clickable and change on click I have used a sprite pattern so when a new image should be displayed I just position the background to the next image. The image looks like this:

[image]

The issue is when I try to adapt these buttons to smaller screens by changing width or height the resizing happens on the whole image instead of just the one element I wish to resize.

Is there any method to "lock" the displayed element when using this background positioning so that when I want to make the element larger or smaller it just applies to the element and not the whole sprite image?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301296/8620333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the translateY property of transform when it will hover over or click the button.

#### This might solve your problem.

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0];
var sprite = document.getElementsByClassName('sprite_image')[0];
var count = 0;
button.onclick = function() {
  if (count % 2 == 0) {
    sprite.style.transform = "translateY(-136px)";
  } else {
    sprite.style.transform = "translateY(-1px)";
  }
  count++;
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.sprite {
  width: 55px;
  height: 63px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sprite img {}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-63px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-126px);
  }
}

.sprite button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sprite button:hover .sprite_image {
  transform: translateY(-68px);
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite">
  <button class="button"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GrWU.png" class="sprite_image"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there not a simpler solution for this? Maybe some CSS keyword to "lock" the image? This is quite complex for my needs and I will rather just have multiple sprite images with different sizes and load them accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelMunta As far as i know this can be done with the help of javascript if you could tell me what you want to do with the help of sprite image resizing maybe that can be done with css itself