# Calc for a Background-Position when a Calc is used for Width and Height

Tags: css, background-position

I have a `div`, where I will put an icon from a file with a load of icons in it. I also need to scale the icon. So I use the normal `width`, `height`, `background-position`, `background-size` to sort it all out.

```
<div style="background: url(images/touchbuttons.png); width: min(10vw, 10vh); height: min(10vw, 10vh); background-position: -min(10vw, 10vh) 0px; background-size: 700% 200%;" >
</div>
```

The graphic has 7 icons wide and 2 icons high. (Hence the `700%` and `200%` on `background-size`.)

I calculate the `width` and `height` of the `div` based on 10% of the minimum of `vw` or `vh`.

No worries so far. To get the top left icon in the png file, `background-position: 0px 0px;` works perfectly.

**Question: So how do I get the second icon in the png, ie 2nd to the right on the top row? When I do `background-position: -min(10vw, 10vh) 0px;`, which is the obvious choice, it gives the same result as `background-position: 0px 0px;`. It does not seem to be doing the `calc`. Why?**

Comment: `-min(10vw, 10vh)` is invalid use `max(-10vw, -10vh)` or `calc(-1* min(10vw, 10vh))`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301296/8620333 (check the last snippet where you can use CSS variable to simplify things)

Comment: @Temani Afif - Thanks, that did the trick. If you put that as an answer, I will Tick it.